# what is a declaration(?) like "GLenum GlewInitResult = glewInit();" doing?

Tags: c, opengl, enums, return-value, declaration

I'm hoping you readers wont mind answering my simple request here.

```
GLenum GlewInitResult = glewInit();
```

I want to make sure I'm understanding this right.

Is GLenum setting GlewInitResult as a a uint?

And is GlewInitResult being assigned to only the return value of glewInit()?

Or to further ask, whats the difference between

```
GLenum GlewInitResult = glewInit();
```

and

```
GLenum GlewInitResult = glewInit; //this statement gives me a type mismatch error
```

What does removing the parenthesis do in a declaration(?) like this?

Sorry if this is trivial question. I just want to make sure I'm grasping/understanding the overall concept of opengl programming with freeglut.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It declares a variable named `GlewInitResult` and assigns the result of the function call `glewInit` to the variable.

You can see it as two steps:

1. Declare variable
2. Assign result of function call to variable

I.e. the same as

```
GLenum GlewInitResult;
GlewInitResult = glewInit();
```

This is **very** basic stuff, and should have been in the very first chapter of any C (or C++) book. It has **nothing** to do with OpenGL or the GLEW library.

As for your second question, the first *calls* the function `glewInit` and stores the returned result in the variable. The second tries to store a *pointer to the function* in the variable, and as the variable is declared of the wrong type you get an error.

Comment: Just to expand on Joachim's last point, the name of the function alone in C is evaluated to a pointer to the actual address of the compiled code in memory (usually not what you want, but when it is, you'll know it).  The parentheses after the function name are syntax to show that you want to call (execute) that function instead, and assign the return value to the variable on the left side of the expression.  The compiler looks at the left side of the expression first and then expects the thing on the right side to have the same type or be convertible to it, which a function pointer can't be.

Comment: You guys rock, thank you! I have trouble reading, so I'm not really able to read any books on just about anything, so I went through some video tutorials that didn't fully cover this particular subject.